# Databinding to DocumentViewer.Document Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, documentviewer

I have a view that contains a DocumentViewer control and I have another class that has a property that exposes a FixedDocumentSequence and implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I am trying to databind the document property of the documentviewer to the FixedDocumentSequence property, when I run it the documentviewer does not load the FixedDocumentSequence. All ofthe other bindings in the view are working but not this one.

Here are the code snippets any help would be appreciated, hopefully it is something trivial that I am forgeting.

```
public class Generator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const string _fixedDocumentSequencePropertyName = "Fixed Document Sequence";


    private FixedDocumentSequence _fixedDocumentSequence;
    public FixedDocumentSequence FixedDocumentSeq
    {
        get { return _fixedDocumentSequence; }
        private set
        {
            this._fixedDocumentSequence = value;
            onPropertyChanged(_fixedDocumentSequencePropertyName);
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }

    #endregion
}
```

and here is the relevant xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <generator:Generator x:Key="gen"/>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StyleDictionary.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/AnimationDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
          Margin="0,0,0,20" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource gen}}">
        <DocumentViewer Name="documentViewer1" Margin="6,180,8,0" Visibility="Visible" Document="{Binding Path=FixedDocumentSeq, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the get called?   Try returning IDocumentPaginatorSource.  You should be able to cast the _fixedDocumentSequence to IDocumentPaginatorSource.

Comment: If I set a breakpoint on the get, it is hit when the window first loads but not after.  I tried with IDocumentPaginatorSource but no luck, the cast works but the result is the same.

Comment: The other thing you can do is create a pass through converter with a catch block and some times the catches an error.   You are sure the document is not just blank?

Comment: Try calling NotifyPropopertyChanged("FixedDocumentSeq");  If get is  only getting called on the load then you need to look at set.

Comment: I am 99.7% sure that the document is not blank. I will try your suggestions. BalamBalam, thanks for the advice.  I will let you know how it turns out.  Will have a result by 17.00GMT 20.12

Comment: Okay the issue has been resolved.  It was an issue of pure stupidity.  The name that I was passing into the onPropertyChanged method was not the same as the name of the property that changed. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: And you are not give me credit?  See my my commment "Try calling NotifyPropopertyChanged("FixedDocumentSeq"); If get is only getting called on the load then you need to look at set."